# Stuck in loading page after login

Tags: orocrm

I was able to install OroCRM using this [guide](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-orocrm-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-with-apache2-mariadb-and-php-7-1/) but I installed the latest nodeJS, PHP, and OroCRM 4.1

Now after login I'm just stuck on a [loading page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8RNb.png). I have tried searching but the only one I have found relevant to my problem is [this](https://forum.oroinc.com/orocrm/orocrm-installationtechnical-issues-or-problems/topic/stuck-on-loading...-after-login/) but it didn't resolve my problem. These are the [dev](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ALxRtO7l1mQWFuzc6yc8Stzxz1Q86J5B/view?usp=sharing) and [prod](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uVPAJKa1r_xeLAFc4k_D1B26IK0XDl3O/view?usp=sharing) logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks assets (JS and CSS) are not loaded. The issue could happen because of the incorrect configuration for the webserver (nginx or apache) or the absences of generated assets.

Please try to regenerate the assets by running

```
php bin/console oro:assets:install --env=prod
```

and make sure there are no errors in the command output.

If it doesn't help - check your webserver config.

Here are the official OroCRM recommendations according to the server setup
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/web-server-config/